# saving the replacements in a text file - matlab

Tags: matlab

i need to replace a particular string in a text file in Matlab and save it in a new text file. here's my code, it shows the corrects replacement in Command Window but the new file is steal identical.

```
fin = fopen('mooj1.txt');
fout = fopen('copy of mooj1.txt');

while ~feof(fin)
s = fgetl(fin);
s = strrep(s, '57.0833 30.2833', '53.0833 -28.2833');
fprintf(fout,'%s',s);
disp(s)
end
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fout = fopen('copy of mooj1.txt','w');
```

open the file as write mode with `'w'` (in the second line of your code)

**Full code:**

```
fin = fopen('mooj1.txt');
fout = fopen('copy of mooj1.txt','w');

while ~feof(fin)
    s = fgetl(fin);
    s = strrep(s, '57.0833 30.2833', '53.0833 -28.2833');
    fprintf(fout,'%s',s);
    disp(s)
end
fclose(fin);
fclose(fout);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Lilybentham worked for me.. i guess you added `'w'` for both files. copy the full code and try it. I'm getting the same results as in the cmd prompt

Comment: does it change the text file for you?! it makes no different for my code.

Comment: it did.. rechecked @Lilybentham

Comment: this is only generating a new text file not editing the exist text file

Comment: @Lilybentham It wont create a new file when there is already a file with same file name. Also whats wrong in creating a new file? you got one without edited and one with edited. That is what you need, rite?

Comment: @Lilybentham U said you got correct replacements in `CMD` window. Using this code, i'm getting the same results in the file as in `CMD` window. Are you getting the same results?

Comment: yes, I'm getting the same result!
i wanted to edit the text file itself, but i think you're right, nothing is wrong with having tow text file!

Answer (score 1):

```
dlmwrite('copy of mooj1.txt',s,'delimiter',' ','precision',12);
```

and you will save in a txt the array "s"

```
fin = fopen('mooj1.txt');

while ~feof(fin) 
   s = fgetl(fin); 
   s = [s, ' 57.0833 30.2833 ', ' 53.0833 -28.2833 ']; 
   disp(s) 
end 

fclose(fin); 
dlmwrite('copy of mooj1.txt',s,'delimiter','','precision',12);
```